# What are alternative tools for searching files in full content?

Tags: linux, text-processing, sed, grep, awk

I realized that most of the text related tools I use, grep/egrep/awk/sed are line-oriented.
I guess that is a simplified approach to search in files but I was wondering if there is another set of tools operating on file level that I am not aware.

So are there other tools that search over the full contents of a file without using the line mode?

Comment: Is there a point?

Comment: @gnp:Yes, learning how to use the proper tools for the proper job

Comment: "Proper job" for what?

Comment: @OneOfOne:For searching.If I am interested in patterns across lines I am using the wrong tools

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18384/is-there-a-tool-in-linux-that-allows-multi-line-regex-expressions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### grep

If you're only interested in the names of the files that contain a search string 1 time you can use `grep` with its `-l` switch to do this.

#### Example

Say I have 2 files full of numbers.

```
$ seq 100 > sample1.txt
$ seq 100 > sample2.txt
```

Now if I search that file for occurrences of the string "10".

```
$ grep -l 10 sample*.txt 
sample1.txt
sample2.txt
```

It will only return the files that contain a match 1 time, even if there are multiple lines that match. As proof, if I take the `-l` switch out:

```
$ grep 10 sample*.txt 
sample1.txt:10
sample1.txt:100
sample2.txt:10
sample2.txt:100
```

#### pcregrep

If you want to search for patterns across multiple lines you can use `pcregrep` along with its `-M` switch, for multi-line.

```
$ pcregrep -M "11[\n,]*.*12" sample*
sample1.txt:11
12
sample2.txt:11
12
```

Answer (score 2):

Perl gives you a "file slurp" mode:

```
echo "foo
bar
baz" |
perl -0777 -ne 'print "found it" if /foo\s+bar/'
```

The `-0777` option is the key. The whole file gets read into memory, where you can operate on it.

Answer (score 1):

For code, there's [ack](http://beyondgrep.com/), it's awesome and can be language-specific or language-agnostic.

Comment: I don't think that this is *not* line oriented. Since you pass how many lines around the match to display it seems to me it operates line by line

Comment: maybe give an example of what you're trying to match?

Comment: ack searches are line-based, just like grep.

Answer (score 1):

GNU coreutils documentation is nicely organized around files, lines, fields, and character oriented operations and tools that work on them. Check it out [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html).